# What is means message "Ignored" in LibreNMS logs?

Tags: hp-procurve

I use LibreNMS for monitoring. There is device HP J8697A Switch E5406zl, it added to monitoring. I see this messages - "Ignored IP":

[image]

What is it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I checked out the source and did a grep, it looks like it comes from this:

```
includes/discovery/discovery-arp.inc.php:        log_event("Ignored $ip", $deviceid, 'interface', 3, $if);
```

A further check into the code it looks like this:

```
if (! match_network(Config::get('nets'), $ip)) {
    echo 'i';
    log_event("Ignored $ip", $deviceid, 'interface', 3, $if);
    continue;
}
```

This appears to be correct, we do not do auto-discovery and the autodiscovery list is empty. We do have networks that we ignore, for obvious reasons, because it's not ours.

Disable arp discovery under Global Settings, Discovery, Discovery modules.